# enabling or disabling validation for a particular EditTextView dynamically though program

Tags: java, android, validation

MainActivity.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/first_name_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_height_patient"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/text_input_height"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:maxLength="35"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size"
            android:padding="10dp"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>






    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/last_name_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_height_patient"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/last_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/text_input_height"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
            android:hint="Last Name"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:maxLength="35"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>






    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_height_patient"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_low"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/doctors_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
            android:gravity="left">
        </Spinner>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/ref_name_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_height_patient"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reference"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/text_input_height"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
            android:hint="Reference"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="70"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Submit"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private EditText firstName;
    private EditText lastName;
    private Spinner selDoc;
    private EditText reference;
    private Button submitBut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstName = findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        lastName = findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        selDoc = findViewById(R.id.doctors_list);
        reference = findViewById(R.id.reference);
        submitBut = findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

        String[] dicList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doctors_list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> docAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dicList);
        selDoc.setAdapter(docAdapter);

        setOnListnerClickedItems();
        setListeners();

    }


    private void setOnListnerClickedItems() {

        submitBut.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setListeners() {

        lastName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.submit_button:

                String errorMsg = validate();

                if (errorMsg.toString().isEmpty()) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }




    private String validate() {
        if (ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(firstName).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Enter Your First Name";
        }
        else if (!Validator.isValidName(ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(firstName))) {
            return "Please Enter Valid First Name";
        }
        else if (ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(lastName).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Enter Your Last Name";
        }
        else  if (!Validator.isValidName(ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(lastName))) {
            return "Please Enter Valid Last Name";
        }
        else if (ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(selDoc).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Select Doctor";
        }
        else if (ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(reference).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Enter Reference Name";
        }
        else if (!Validator.isValidReferenceName(ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(reference))) {
            return "Please Enter Valid Reference Name";
        }

        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I have 4 fields in the form including **firstName, lastName, doctorList, and referenceName**. I need to validate all the fields excluding INVISIBLE fields. 
As given in the code 3 fields are visible and 1 field i.e. lastName is invisible. But, when I am entering data and clicking on the submit button it's showing error as Please Enter the Last Name. How to validate only visible fields dynamically? Please help me.

Comment: Yeah with invisible edittext you are able to get text from edittext. So you need to change visibility from `INVISIBLE` to `GONE`.

Comment: did that way too. still, not working @Piyush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you need  to check the visibility of the field and apply validation among them

For example:

```
//To check the visibilty of the filed 
if(edittLastName.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
    vaildateField();
}
```

Validation Function :

```
private void vaildateField(){
    if(etxLastName.getLength()==0)
        Log.e("Error","Enter last name");
}
```

Comment: I want to disable that invisible field dynamically. This is sample code. For this time lastName field is invisible but nexttime maybe another fields will be invisible. So for that i need to validate visible fields only.

Comment: for every field i need to make separate method to validate it. I am validating all fields in single method. How do I escape that single field which is invisible.

Comment: No, it's a basic, you need to apply your own logic or maintain a boolean value, don't expect for full code. I just give the key for playing with visibility of the field

Comment: Let me know, if it works and if you feel any difficulty then ask

Comment: working by putting  this code with every field                                                                                 
 if (firstName.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE &&
   ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(firstName).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Enter Your First Name";
        }

Answer (score 0):

Add boolean value

```
boolean isneedValidation=false;

        else if (isneedValidation &&ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(selDoc).toString().isEmpty()) {
                return "Please Enter Your Email ID";
            }
```

if isneedValidation is true condition will check otherwise it will skip
    whenever you want to change the Edittext to visible at the time change the boolean value

Comment: no need to take boolean isneedValidation=false;                                                               
 working by putting  this code                                                                                    
 if (firstName.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE &&
               ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(firstName).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Enter Your First Name";
        }

Answer (score 0):

This is the certain answer of your question.

```
private String validate() {
        if (firstName.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(firstName).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Enter Your First Name";
        }
        else if (firstName.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && !Validator.isValidName(ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(firstName))) {
            return "Please Enter Valid First Name";
        }
        else if (lastName.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(lastName).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Enter Your Last Name";
        }
        else  if (lastName.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && !Validator.isValidName(ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(lastName))) {
            return "Please Enter Valid Last Name";
        }
        else if (selDoc.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(selDoc).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Select Doctor";
        }
        else if (reference.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(reference).toString().isEmpty()) {
            return "Please Enter Reference Name";
        }
        else if (reference.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && !Validator.isValidReferenceName(ComponentUtils.getInputStringFromView(reference))) {
            return "Please Enter Valid Reference Name";
        }

        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is also what @user:5978440 tried to explain you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have done with the same technique. It's working fine